# Datatables expect Array but was given Object (and breaks when it expect Object)

Tags: jquery, datatables

**Scenario**

We have this employees table, that looks like this:

[image]

that contains 16,530 employee rows. As expected, this table takes more than 30 seconds to load. I have been tasked with speeding it up somehow.

As a stop-gap, we blocked this UI with a loading screen when the page is loading.

**What we were doing**

1. Get all the employees from the API, for a store
2. For each employee

   - convert it into an `Employee` object
   - get its HTML representation (via template rendering)
   - push that HTML representation into a collection
3. initialize the Datatables object with that collection
4. adjust the Datatables columns and draw the table

**What I'm doing now**

1. Get all the employees from the API, for a store
2. For each employee

   - convert it into an `Employee` object
   - push that object into a collection
3. initialize the Datatables object with that collection
4. adjust the Datatables columns and draw the table

   - On `rowCallback`, do the custom rendering logic

**Implementation**

On `$(document).ready`, we have the following table setup logic:

```
var addbutton =
      '<button onclick="PopModel()" class="btn btn-success float-sm-left rounded"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Employee</button>'
    var table_height = $('#with-content')
      .height() - 175
    var table = InitializeDatatable('#data-table', table_height, addbutton, 1, {
      paging: true,
      pageLength: 50,
      deferRender: true,
  /**
   * Invoked when a row is being created
   * @param {DomRow} row the row that datatables comes up with
   * @param {Object | Array} data the data we pass to datatables for the current row
   */
  createdRow: function(row, data) {
     data[0] = 'some image'
  },
  /**
   * Invoked after a row has been created
   * @param {DomRow} row the row that datatables comes up with
   * @param {Object | Array} data the data we pass to datatables for the current row
   */
  rowCallback: function(row, data) { 
    // render (or replace!) row here
    setTimeout(function() { 
      let employeeRowTR = new Employee()
        .ExtractFrom(data)
        .ToHTML()
      $(row).html(employeeRowTR.html())
    }, 4)
  }
})

let start = Date.now()
    GetEmployees(function (result, success) {
      if (success) {
        let tableRows  = []
        var ran = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          const element = result[i];
          // progress bar logic
          setTimeout(function () {
            ran++;
            // adjust the progress bar state if it is defined
            if ($progressBar != null) {
              var percentValue = (ran / result.length) * 100
              $progressBar
                .css('width', percentValue + "%")
              if (percentValue == 100) {
                $('.dataTables_scrollBody')
                  .LoadingOverlay('hide')
              }
            }
            // extract an Employee object and add its HTML representation to datatables
            var employee = new Employee()
              .ExtractFrom(element)
            tableRows.push(employee)

            if (ran == result.length) { 
              table.rows.add(tableRows)
              table.columns.adjust()
                .draw();
            }
            if (ran == 50) {
              $('.dataTables_scrollBody')
                .LoadingOverlay("show", {
                  image: "",
                  custom: $progressBarDiv
                });
              $progressBar = $('#progressbar .progress-bar')
            }
          }, 1)
        }

        if (result.length == 0 && $('#task-selectpicker option')
          .length == 0) {
          Alert("It looks like there are no tasks created, would you like to create them before creating your employees?", "This can make things easier when setting up your employees.", function () {
            window.location = '/task/index'
          })
        }

      } else {
        var response = new ErrorResponse(result.responseText)
        response.Show()
      }
    })
```

Our **`InitializeDatatable`** is defined to be:

```
// Datatables
function InitializeDatatable(selector, table_height, addbutton, autoColumn = 0, customOptions = {}) {
  var randomButtonID = RandomID()
  var defaultOptions = {
    dom: `<"${randomButtonID}-addbutton">frtip`,
    scrollY: table_height,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: true,
    info: false,
    order: [
      [autoColumn, 'asc']
    ],
    deferRender : true
  }
  $.extend(defaultOptions, customOptions)
  var table = $(selector)
    .DataTable(defaultOptions)

  $(`div.${randomButtonID}-addbutton`)
    .html(addbutton)
  return table
}
```

Note that, once employees are fetched from the database, we convert those into `Employee` objects, which have the following HTML representation logic:

```
ToHTML() {
    // load in the employee template
    if (employeeTemplate == null) {
      employeeTemplate = FetchTemplate('employee/employee.html', "employee-template");
    }
    // render it with this
    var $element = employeeTemplate.tmpl(this);
    // get the picture and attach it directly to the view element that's being rendered
    this.GetPicture(function (picture) {
      $element.find('.person-image')
        .attr('src', picture.Picture)
        .data(picture);
    });
    // attach this model data to the view element and return it.
    return $element.data("model", this);
  }
```

**Table element (fetched from back end)**

```
<div id="with-content" class="table-full">
    <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="95%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Active</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**The problem**

This code, as it is written now, expects each `data` object to be Array, thus it complains on page load:

[image]

Dismissing the alert will show the table row elements, but when you click the next page, the alert pops up again. [image].

Specifying some [`columns`](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/object_data.html) like this:

```
columns : [
    { data : "Id" },
    { data : "FirstName" },
    { data : "LastName" },
    { data : "IsActive" }
  ]
```

creates the following problem:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: You'd need to decompose your problem further, this is too much to read...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code.

1. When using DataTables you should never manipulate DOM directly like you're doing with `$(row).html(employeeRowTR.html())`. To alter appearance of each cell, either use [`columns.render()`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render()) for each column or generate HTML markup for the whole table and only then initialize DataTables plugin.
2. To speed-up the loading with large datasets, consider using [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) instead.

Comment: > use `columns.render`



is this also the way to go for async operations like fetching image URLs from the API? I was trying to do it in `createdRow`, but it wasn't ready when `rowCallback` got invoked.

Comment: I fixed the issue and might elaborate, today, on what all I did.